# Things that must be considered when mass producing a capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance, electronics, dielectric

The question is to list four things that must be considered when a capacitor is chosen for inclusion in a circuit which is to be mass produced.

Are there a specific set of four things? I've come up with only three so far which are: dielectric, charge and potential difference.

Comment: Four things? You mean price, availability, reliability and size? Sure, why not. :-)

Comment: boo^ I need helpful answers

Comment: "four things that must be considered when a capacitor is chosen for inclusion in a circuit which is to be mass produced."

Comment: Your mass is confusing for weight.

Comment: mass produce  = produce  hundreds and thousands

Comment: Those are the first four criteria that an experienced EE will look at when choosing a capacitor for an actual circuit that has to be mass produced. :-)

Comment: I suggest "Things that must be
considered for mass
production of a capacitor" as title.

Comment: Do you wish to open a factory? Then, cost of production and shipment are most important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider shape, capacitance, size , max.  voltage/current it can withstand.

Try to look at some capacitor, may be from your house fan. (They generally burn after some time.)

You will find your answer.

Economically, CuriousOne answers correctly.

Comment: You will never get to market with that approach. If your capacitor is too expensive, your boss will cut it out from production. If it isn't available, you can't produce anything. If it isn't reliable, your product will not even get trough the test phase and it it's too big, your product will not sell well. At least we are agreeing on the size. :-)

Comment: Yes but this is a first year engineering exam

Comment: We don't talk about economics of capacitors at this stage in the course. Maybe in a couple of years we will

Comment: @Saxasianguy: When you get out of school, you will find yourself in a job market that only hires engineers with 5 years of more of actual experience. You know why? Because what they will want to hear from you in the job interview are "price, availability, reliability and size" and you will tell them about capacitance, voltage rating and maybe leakage and temperature range (if you were among the best in your class). :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne I very well agree to you completely. I just gave some more ex. OP was looking for. I said you are correct in answer.

Comment: @Saxasianguy You don't need Engineering Ist year for this. You study it in high school. Class 12 chapter 2.